# Do I need to prep/clean a new redwood fence before I apply sealer?

Tags: cleaning, fence, sealing

I just finished installing a redwood privacy fence two days ago. I want to seal it as soon as possible before it starts to weather.

I am going to use [this product from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-Premium-1-gal-T-500-Natural-Clear-Transparent-Waterproofing-Exterior-Wood-Finish-50001/100113076) but it recommends that I clean the fence with [this solution first.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-Premium-1-gal-All-In-One-Wood-and-Deck-Cleaner-06301N/203200559)

Do I really need to do that with a brand new fence?

Answer (score 1):

If the wood hasn't been pressure treated and is dry and clean, I'd skip the cleaning solution. If it has been pressure treated, the product suggests you wait a few months to let the wood "air out". In that case, you'd want to then use the cleaning solution.

Comment: The rails are pressure treated 2x4, but the pickets are redwood, not pressure treated.